# Beat frequency in instruments

Tags: acoustics

I was recently learning about beat frequencies, that is, when sound waves slightly out of phase overlap and result in a beat. I thought that this sounded similar to the vibrato in stringed instruments. I am just curious to know if these phenomena are inter-related or if they are separate.

I think they would be inter-related. A violinist playing a vibrato would, I think, be altering the tension in the violin string and thus changing its frequency. The two different frequencies would overlap to create a beat. I am not sure about this though.

Video example of vibrato: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP9Jbox5S9A
[reference video, I do not own it]
Based on the above video, however, I am not sure.

Thanks,
~

Comment: They're not really related. Vibrato creates different frequencies but you don't hear them at the same time, which is what what creates beats.

Comment: Okay, thank you @RogerJBarlow . So if vibrato is not created by beats, then what is the principle  behind it? And why does the vibrato sound like the 'wobble' of a beat?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has been answered in various ways in music.stackexchange

Comment: Vibrato is caused (in bowed instruments) by changing string length, not tension.  OTOH vibrato in guitars -- see "whammy bar" -- can be achieved with tension changes. In either case, vibrato is  sinusoidal frequency variation.  "Beats" are sinusoidal amplitude variation.

Comment: Okay, makes sense, thanks @CarlWitthoft .